# how to calculate height and width of image

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have server side image control as:

```
  <img id="img" runat="server" style="padding-left:20px" 
       src="~/Images/2013-02-14_225913.png" />
```

I want to calculate its height and width. I did it as:

```
int iWidth = (int)Math.Round((decimal)img.Width.Value);
int iHeight = (int)Math.Round((decimal)img.Height.Value);
```

This returns -0, not actual parameters.

How can I get the H & W of the image control?

Comment: If your `img` is of the `Image` class, just `img.Height` should give you the pixel height in integers.

Comment: Are you trying to get the control's size or the image's real size?

Comment: As a remark, the `img` object will not have the `.Value` properties, as it is instantiated as `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage` on the server side. If you would have used `<asp:Image />`, then the class would have bee `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`, which has the `.Value` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap btmp;
string image = "~/Images/2013-02-14_225913.png";
myBitmap = new Bitmap(image);

int height= btmp.Height;
int weight = btmp.Width;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But the problem is image path is from another site, not from the application. say the path is: http://xyz/subsite/folder/img1.jpg    so when we take this path, it throws error. How can we create bitmap object using this path/image

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, so there are two scenarios:

1. If you are referring to the control's properties, then you can only get the size if you actually assign the control's properties in the `.aspx`/`.ascx` file.

   There are two separate classes being used:

   ```
   <img id="img1" runat="server" 
       style="padding-left: 20px"
       src="meSepiaLarge.jpg" 
       width="100" height="100" />
   <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" 
       ImageUrl="~/meSepiaLarge.jpg"  
       Width="100px" Height="100px" />
   ```

   `img1` will be instantiated as a `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage` on the server side, while the `img2` will be a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`. Here is how to get their dimensions.

   ```
   int i1Width = (int)Math.Round((decimal)img1.Width);
   int i1Height = (int)Math.Round((decimal)img1.Height);

   int i2Width = (int)Math.Round((decimal)img2.Width.Value);
   int i2Height = (int)Math.Round((decimal)img2.Height.Value);
   ```
2. If you are referring to the source image's size, then you can look at [kad1r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14891731/674700).

Comment: Thanks. Kad1r's answer worked. But the problem is image path is from another site, not from the application. say the path is: xyz/subsite/folder/img1.jpg         so when we take this path, it throws error. How can we create bitmap object using this path/image

Answer (score 0):

You have to load it into memory & calculate height & width

```
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/images/lightbulb.png"));
        if (myBitmap != null)
        {
            Response.Write("Height:"+ myBitmap.Height + " & width:"+ myBitmap.Width);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But the problem is image path is from another site, not from the application. say the path is: http://xyz/subsite/folder/img1.jpg    so when we take this path, it throws error. How can we create bitmap object using this path/image